# Liferay link to other language page

Tags: hyperlink, internationalization, liferay, freemarker

I am using freemarker template on Liferay Portal CE 6.2 and my site has 2 languages (italian and english). Is there any variable or function to get the link to the same page in the other language?

Example: I am on page `/en/operations` and I want that by clicking on the "italian" button the browser goes to `/it/attivita`, which is the translated page specified on pages admin.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on the liferay forum: https://web.liferay.com/it/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/74709035

```
<#assign languageUrl = portletURLFactory.create(request, "82", layout.getPlid(), "ACTION_PHASE") />
${languageUrl.setParameter( "struts_action", "/language/view" )}
${languageUrl.setParameter( "redirect", theme_display.getURLCurrent() )}
${languageUrl.setPortletMode( "view" )}
${languageUrl.setWindowState( "normal" )}
${languageUrl.setParameter( "languageId", "xx_XX" )}
```

set the xx_XX to the locale you want to switch to and add a link to languageUrl:

```
<a href="${languageUrl}">Italian</a>
```